# Migrate wallet from Bitcoin Core to Armory

Tags: armory

I have installed Armory.  I have created a wallet within the Armory.  I however would like to use a wallet I have with bitcoin core.  I am unsure how to do this.  Thank you for the help.

All I have is the wallet.dat

I have uninstalled bitcoin core and when I reinstall I have no idea how to use the wallet there either.  Ultimately I have wallet.dat and I'm unsure how to get that file into the Armory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to simply send them from the bitcoin core wallet to an address in armory wallet.

The other option would require you to use dumpprivkey on each address and then importprivkey on armory.

Comment: I have added some notes.  I'm sorry I did not provide complete information.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: unfortunately you can't https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=154375.0 download core again and send the funds once you sync the blockchain.

Comment: Doesn't Armory use `bitcoind`? It seems Armory could directly use Bitcoin Core's `wallet.dat`, then.